# Apply NonlinearModelFit to an image

Tags: fitting, performance-tuning

I have several images (in FITS format), which I want to fit with a 2D-Gaussian distribution. The problem is that `NonlinearModelFit` expects data in the form of a matrix. Therefore, I first transform the imported images via

```
Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]] pixelsize, #2[[2]] pixelsize, #1} &, imaData, {2}], 1]
```

where `imaData` is generated by

```
imaData = ImageData@ Import[image][[1]]
```

and `pixelsize` is just a constant factor (5.3 µm/pixel in my case)

This works, but it is very slow even for images with 1280x1084 pixels. Is there any more elegant solution to my problem?

[Here](http://www.filedropper.com/0000000e02005201515-09-41) is one of my image files.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: ... and also the fitting code you tried?

Comment: are you saying the code show here is too slow? Or the `NonLinearModelFit`?

Comment: the fitting is not a problem, but the transformation of the image data  takes a while.

Comment: That's a PNG file you put in, not a TIFF file. Consider using a filehost to upload your TIFF file.

Comment: your `Flatten..` code runs in about 5 seconds with some synthetic data.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It also takes around 5 seconds on my computer, this is too much, if I have 10-20 images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's take look at your version:

```
pixelsize = 5.3;
(flatimaData = 
    Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]] pixelsize, #2[[2]] pixelsize, #1} &, 
      imaData, {2}], 1];) // AbsoluteTiming
(* 2.44 seconds *)
```

Now I try it with `Table` instead of `MapIndexed`:

```
dims = Dimensions@imaData;
(flatimaData2 = Flatten[
        Table[{i*pixelsize, j*pixelsize, imaData[[i, j]]},
          {i, dims[[1]]}, {j, dims[[2]]}], 1];) // AbsoluteTiming
(* 1.48 seconds *)

flatimaData == flatimaData2
(* True *)
```

Finally, I've compiled the `Table[]` version for a further speed-up.

```
compileConvert = Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {pix, _Real}},
  Module[{dims},
   dims = Dimensions@data;
   Flatten[Table[{i*pix, j*pix, data[[i, j]]}, 
     {i, dims[[1]]}, {j, dims[[2]]}], 1]
   ]
  ]
(flatimaData3 = compileConvert[imaData, pixelsize];) // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.11 seconds *)

flatimaData == flatimaData3
(* True *)
```

Comment: There is a significat speed up with `table`, but I have problem with the compilation. My command is `imaDims = Dimensions@imaData;
imaDataIndex = 
 Compile[{{imaData, _Integer, 2}, {imaDims, _Real, 
    2}, {pixelsize, _Real}}, 
  Flatten[Table[{i*pixelsize, j*pixelsize, imaData[[i, j]]}, {i, 
     imaDims[[1]]}, {j, imaDims[[2]]}], 1]]`, but I get this error `Compile::cpintlt: "i at position 2 of imaData$13017[[i,j]] should be either a nonzero integer or a vector of nonzero integers; evaluation will use the uncompiled function."`

Comment: @phidelio **a)** `imaData` is real-valued, not integers, it should be `{imaData, _Real, 2}` **b)** `imaDims` is not a real matrix but an integer vector, so should be `{imaDims, _Integer, 1}`. Why did you modify the code compared to my example? I suggest taking a look at the documentation for [`Compile[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html)

Comment: @blocwave Great, thank you. I thought I had them correctly. I modified your code, because it fits better to my notebook this way. However, I tried to keep the main idea intact.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.